# Thread synchronisation And Isolation levels

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, transactions, isolation-level

I am learning about the isolation levels at db. I have a doubt, for example with JAVA if we made sure that only one thread can make db update/create call at a time with synchronised block and methods, do we need to enforce isolation levels at db? similarly, if we have serialisable isolation at db do we need to make threads synchronised?

Consider a booking system. How do we make sure that no two people to book the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With databases, you can have connections from different processes on the same machine or even from different machines.

Because a synchronized block only has meaning in a single process, a synchronized block doesn't work with multiple processes from the same machine and therefore also not from processes of different machines.

So a synchronized block is not a replacement for database isolation levels.

Comment: then just making db transaction to have serialisable isolation is enough? coz any transaction originating from any system would  come to db and the db can execute them serially

Comment: Yes. It is the task of the database to make the transactions appear to run sequentially. Keep in mind that Serializable can be pretty expensive; ofter lower isolation levels are used in production environments.